# What do all these letters/numbers in early Samsung ROM file name mean?

Tags: samsung, rom

*This question covers early Samsung ROMs if your ROM looks like this example `G930FXXU2EREM_G930FOJV2ERE8_TUR.zip` then see [this updated question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/what-do-the-numbers-and-letters-in-the-samsung-firmware-mean)*

---

I'm guessing the first 5 letters/numbers are for the model of the device `I8160XXLL2`, but what after that? Is there any guide to understand what exactly they mean by these letters? I'm confused it seems sometimes they repeat the model of the device twice?

```
I8160XXLL2_I8160QXXL3.zip
I8160XXLL2_QXELL3.zip
```

Comment: Who knows... it varies by device and the developers naming convention. Probably best to ask the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2 firmware names are a good demonstration of (early) Samsung naming conventions.

- `I8160XXLL2` is the "PDA" designator, i.e. build number;
- `I8160QXXLL3` is the "CSC" designator, i.e. baseband version.

There can be multiple CSCs corresponding to a single PDA, released for different regions.

Inside the string:

- `I8160` is, obviously the model number;
- `XX` is for country/region (XX itself means Europe or international);
- `LL2` are the release date and version (within same month): first `L` for year (L for 2012, M for 2013, etc.), second `L` for month (A for January, L for December, etc.), and `2` for the 2nd version.

Furthermore, you can pinpoint which exact region the firmware is for by using a part of the CSC: `QXX`/`QXE` designates the precise region within the one defined in PDA. Match these 3 digits with a list of firmwares (e.g. on [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-ace-2/GT-I8160/)), and you will know what regions received such releases.

Comment: Really good answer, I was searching on this for long time, thanks, I haired from a friend that if they mention the model twice that's mean the ROM contain 4 files, and if not that's mean there is only PDA file or something like that, Is that true?

Comment: Not always - it's still more reliable to just download, unpack and check. Shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Is this an early convention specific to Samsung. Or did other OEMs use this too?