# Installing new firmware: PDA,CSC

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, unbricking, device-firmware

I bricked my phone, and wanted to reinstall the firmware, but I'm not sure if it is enough that the build number matches or do the PDA and CSC numbers also have to much at all costs?
I'm asking this because my firmware is branded, and I wanted the one without brands, but that doesn't have the PDA and CSC that I have (I saved them earlier).

Answer (score 1):

PDA/CSC explained in one of my previous answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183326/what-do-all-these-letters-numbers-in-rom-file-name-mean/183328#183328). As for your situation, there are 2 factors to consider:

- Generally, the release date and version of what you're going to flash should be equal to or newer than what you had on the phone right now, so that it will flash at all. Downgrading is not entirely impossible - on newer devices, bootloader level determines how far you can go back; see part of another answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/explain-dont-downgrade-warnings-when-flashing-stock-firmware/180315#180315).
- If you need certain languages to be present, look into the CSC string and make sure it's from your general region.