# What do the numbers and letters in the Samsung Firmware mean?

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

There are three [sets of numbers and letters in the Samsung firmware zip names](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-firmware/) I'm seeing,

- `G930FXXU2EREM_G930FOJV2ERE8_TUR.zip`

What do the different sets mean,

- `G930FXXU2EREM`
- `G930FOJV2ERE8`
- `TUR`

---

[*For older Samsung ROMs which used a shorter convention see this question.*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183326/7425)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The info of this exact firmware is shown [on this page](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model?record=BD0DDAB96C8311E89F15FA163EE8F90B).

As written, `G930FXXU2EREM` is the PDA version, and `G930FOJV2ERE8` is the CSC version. PDA represents the "core" OS build, while CSC - "Consumer Software Customisation" or "Country Specific Code" (didn't find an official explanation of the acronym) - represents the region-specific customizations. The two, along with "Phone" (baseband), provide tailored experience for the region (`TUR`) such as available language, preloaded apps, optimized cellular performance and battery consumption, etc.

As for the naming convention of the string itself, I've explained that in [a previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183328/150986) of mine, but it needs to be expanded to cover new fields in modern Samsung devices. Let's take your string `G930FXXU2EREM` for example:

- `G930F` is obviously the model number;
- `XX` is for country/region (XX itself means Europe or international);
- `U2E` is the bootloader version, which you should never attempt to downgrade (this is in turn explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180313/explain-dont-downgrade-warnings-when-flashing-stock-firmware/180315#180315));
- `REM` are the release date and version (within same month): `R` for year (Q for 2017, R for 2018, etc.), `E` for month (A for January, E for May, etc.), and `M` for within-month revision.

Answer (score 4):

The first part G930FXXU2EREM is the "serial" for this ROM.

The second part G930FOJV2ERE8 is the "serial" for "previous" ROM (i.e. before an OTA update).

TUR is a region code, this case it's Turkey.

So you can think it's:

```
{to}-{from}-{region}.zip
```

Comment: This isn't correct. `G930FOJV2ERE8` is the CSC. I'll do a separate answer.